# “Elle refuse de boire” or “elle refuse à boire”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I am learning French. I translated 'She refuses to drink' as 'Elle refuse á boire' which was marked wrong and corrected as 'Elle refuse de boire'. Is there any way I could have figured out this usage of 'de boire'. Is there any rule about this?

Comment: You could say "Elle *se* refuse à boire" (she forbids herself to drink) which sounds a little bit old.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is choosing between *à* or *de*.

When you say ***Elle refuse de boire*** you have the verb *refuser*  followed by another verb, *de* is the preposition you have to use after *refuser* when it is followed by another verb (to refuse to do something).

When you say ***Elle refuse à boire*** you still have the verb *refuser*, but in that case it is followed by the noun phrase *à boire*. *À boire* means "a drink / something to drink". It is the same construction as if you said: *Elle refuse le cadeau*. In those two sentences *à boire* or *le cadeau* are direct objects of the verb *refuser*.

Comment: (I'm a French Language Learner). Is **à boire** really a noun phrase??! In this case, is "boire" in "à boire" just a normal noun, or is it a verb, as in "une salle à louer"? Because if "boire" is a verb in "à boire", I didn't know that "à + [infinitive]" could create a noun phrase; I thought "à + [infinitive] only could create an adjective phrase (as in "une salle à louer" = a room "for renting", with "à louer" modifying the "une salle")?

Comment: @silph Indeed, it works as if you'd said "quelque chose à boire". A song that may drive this point home: [à boire](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9GVDFhPhA3U)

Comment: @LukeSawczak, so this means I can say "Est-ce que tu veux à boire chaud?" ("Do you want something hot to drink?") or "Qu'est-ce que tu pense de à boire chaud?" ("What is your opinion of something hot to drink")?

Comment: @silph Good extrapolation. No, I wouldn't say that's possible. Notice that in the expanded version, *chaud* wouldn't go there: « quelque chose **de chaud** à boire ». As far as I know, you would have to say that whole phrase to qualify the « à boire » with any adjective.

Comment: oh no, i had not learned about "de + adjective" before. So a question about that, then: which of these sentence are correct? a) "Je veux un boisson chaud", b) "Je veux un boisson de chaud". That is, does "quelque chose" as a noun act differently than "boisson", when I try to modify it with an adjective? And when do I even use "de + adjective"?

Comment: and as for "à + infinitive": why is "Elle refuse à boire" correct, but "Tu veux à boire?" and "Tu pense de à boire" incorrect?

Comment: @LukeSawczak (adding this comment because I forgot to ping you in my previous two comments, and discovered too late for stackexchange to let me edit them..)

Comment: @silph Between those two, a) is correct (except that *boisson* is feminine). I believe it's just *quelque chose de + adjective* and *quelqu'un de + adjective* that work like that. For the second question... *Tu veux à boire* is fine, but not *Je pense de à boire.* I think the options for *à boire* and *à manger* are generally quite limited. Unfortunately, I don't really know the reason.

Comment: @LukeSawczak You said that the options for **à boire** are limited, but you don't know the reason. Do you know when I'm allowed to use it to stand for **quelque chose à boire**? Is it just anywhere where a preposition (like "de") does NOT precede it, and also where you aren't allowed to put an adjective word (like **chaud**) to modify it? But anywhere else, you can use it?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no rule for which preposition follows a verb in cases like this. You have to look it up in a dictionary to be sure.

> [refuser *de*](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/refuser) faire quelque chose
>
> [continuer *à*](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/continuer) faire quelque chose
>
> [commencer *à*](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/commencer) faire quelque chose
>
> [essayer *de*](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/essayer%20de%20faire%20qch) faire quelque chose

Some verbs can even take different prepositions in different cases. Sometimes there appears to be some logic about this:

> [penser *à* qqch (=think *about* something) / penser qqch *de* qqch (=have an opinion *of* something)](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/penser)

Other times it's hard to discern any method to the madness:

> [jouer *à* (un sport) / jouer *de* (un instrument)](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/jouer)

I don't think there are any rules that account for even that subset, let alone all the other verbs that take either *à* or *de*. So you do have to consult a dictionary and memorize them.

Comment: "continuer" can even be used with "de" (there's an example in the link you provide). As a native speaker I always hesitate between "continuer à" and "continuer de". I'm wondering if there's a nuance between the two.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant There can be a nuance in some cases, it depends on the context . A classic example to grasp the difference is *continuer de boire* and *continuer à boire* (or any other addiction...) (a good explanation [here](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/continuer-a-continuer-de/)).

Comment: *Continuer* and *commencer* can be used with either *à* or *de*.

Answer (score 0):

The use of à or de as a verbal complement is pretty much fixed in French, depending on whether the following infinitive is objective (à) or subjective (de). However sometimes the usage is fluid depending on the mood of the speaker, hence the choice of à or de with verbs such as commencer, continuer, refuser. If a sense of effort is intended to be conveyed, one would tend to use à.

Comment: With *refuser* only *de* is possible. It's with the pronominal verb *se refuser* that the choice between *de* and *à* is possible.

Comment: Ah! yes! I've got it now! The more intensive reflexive form will take à as in se décider à vis-à-vis décider de. It gets confusing because verbs such as commencer and continuer can take either preposition depending on the mood of the speaker. I must avoid any bad habits when using the verb refuser. Thank you.